# How to get related value from SelectList

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Using .NET 5.0 and Azure SQL

I am trying to figure out how to get a related value when I make a selection from a drop down list and pass that value to a hidden input field.

My select list (id="customer" is for the jQuery Chosen plugin):

```
<select id="customer" asp-for="Assignment.Retailer_ASM" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Retailer_ASM">
                <option value="">--Customers--</option>
            </select>
```

So when a user selects a customer from this list, there is a FK value that I want to pass into the hidden input, which is used for RLS.

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Assignment.RlsArea" value="What to put here?" class="form-control" />
```

The value would be like Assignment.Retailer_ASM.RegionID, an INT for the selected Retailer_ASM.

Comment: What is the value and text of options in select?

Comment: Select list will be like {1, 'Grocery Store 1}, {2, 'Grocery Store 2}. However the model will have {1, 'Grocery Store 1', 27}, etc and I need to retrieve that 27 when choosing that store.